# In Android,layout not laying out properly first time but ok the consecutive times

Tags: android, android-layout

I have defined my xml in a relative layout in activity_main.xml. There are about 14 image buttons.  I have set the width and height of the buttons to an arbitrary number.

In the onCreate method of my java class, after the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) statement, I compute and set the width and height of the buttons and spacing between the buttons based on the screen size using DisplayMetrics, and the height and width of the btooons as a fraction the screen size, so that it is uniformly laid out for all screen sizes.

This works fine, but except for the first time the program is loaded on a device..all other times it lays out just fine. Please help me on how to solve this. thankyou